# How can I get the exception object inside a IDispatchMessageInspector?

Tags: c#, wcf, idispatchmessageinspector, operationcontext

My *WCF* application uses an `IDispatchMessageInspector` for some advanced monitoring - *when an error occurs and when no error occurs*.

I'm looking for a way to get the exception that occurred in my service when I get to the `IDispatchMessageInspector.BeforeSendReply` method since I need to perform a specific action based on the exception type.

I'm **not** looking for modifying\logging my errors as I already do that with a custom `IErrorHandler`.

I thought about adding the exception to the `OperationContext` when I'm in the `IErrorHandler` and simply reading it when I'm back in the `IDispatchMessageInspector`, but I prefer something built in.

Is there any way I can fetch the exception when I'm in the `IDispatchMessageInspector.BeforeSendReply` method? Maybe somewhere on the OperationContext?

Answer (score 0):

*`IDispatchMessageInspector` interface* allows you to see the messages arriving at an endpoint before they have been dispatched as well as the corresponding response message before it is sent back to the client.

> *A couple of points to be noticed about the **`BeforeSendReply()`** method that might be useful:*

- If the operation the message was dispatched to was a One-Way
  operation, this method will still be invoked by the WCF runtime on
  your IDispatchMessageInspector implementation when the operation has
  finished its execution. However, the "reply" argument representing
  the response message will be null, so be sure to check for that
  before manipulating the message.
- You can detect in your implementation if the operation the message
  was dispatched to threw an exception/fault, by checking the [IsFault](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.channels.message.isfault.aspx#Exceptions)
  property of the reply message. This will be even true for one-way
  operations *(even though the client will never see it, the server side
  dispatcher still correctly notifies the message inspectors about it)*.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but you are not answering my question. I know I can check if a message has a fault on it and I know when the invocation occurs, I need the Exception instance and I need it inside the IDispatchMessageInspector since I have some monitoring logic that I perform there for success and failure messages.